# automate copy-paste snippet from many html files to other html files

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code, applescript

I am working on a localisation project. I am provided with a snippet of html that needs inserting into an existing full page. how ever many snippets for how ever many languages and the same for full pages. This doesn't happen programmatically or at run time. I have to literally copy and paste them.

I have figured out some regex patterns to quickly match the exact part of the snippet i need and another to match where i am putting it. This speeds up the process a little bit.

What i want to know is, how would i go about automating this provided i can figure out the regex each time it needs doing? some kind of bash script or AppleScript?

Comment: Have **1** template with fields that need to be substituted and **N** files, 1 for each language that have a key-value structure with the translations. Write a script that fills the template with the translations and then serve the page

Comment: are these 'snipptes' actual vscode snippets? Is that why vscode is tagged? Or by snippets do you simply mean sections of code. Either way, can you clarify how you are 'provided' these snippets

Comment: @rioV8 I cant do this at runtime as i have to work within the clients framework and their way of working. I'm expected to do it this way by pm's and lead devs. I'm just a junior trying to automate a very repetitive task. The idea of a key value pair in a script is probably a good start though.

Comment: @soulshined it html snippets. I just added vscode as a tag as i guessed it might have some functionality or extension that might help.

Comment: I see. Well in that case you could use Automator or apple script yeah, since you have the regex already. Is the *receiving* file always the same? The one you send it to? Meaning can it be templated?

Comment: great, i'll have a look into automator and see what does. Thanks.

Comment: there are a lot of html template engines have a look at them like Jinja for python